# duda acerca de una tabla, y cardinalidad en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, relaciones

espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

tengo un problema al momento de crear una base de datos (aun estoy aprendiendo).
necesito crear una  base de datos para una empresa que genere un reporte como el de la imagen.

[image: Reporte a Generar]

tengo creadas las tablas de la siguiente manera, pero tengo un problema en la parte de la tabla de relaciones (t_relaciones). Aclaración: (la tabla de relaciones hace referencia al conjunto de guías que lleva un conductor).

[image: Diseño base da datos y relaciones]

La parte que no se hacer, es crear la tabla relacion, ya que como está en este momento, ingresaria siempre la "id_relacion". y  deberia ser una sola vez (id_relacion, id_conductor) y ahi ingresar  muchas guías,  y el "id_relacion" ingresarlo al reporte (t_remision).

si alguien me puede dar una idea de como hacerlo, o si hay que cambiar lo que sea en la base de datos no importa. Perdón si no me hice entender bien, es mi primer proyecto y quiero hacerlo lo mejor posible.
Gracias.

Comment: Si la tabla de relaciones hace referencia al conjunto de guías que lleva un conductor, no pinta mucho id_relación. Si de la imagen, se "adivina" que una remisión puede tener uno o varios conductores, tendrás otra tabla intermedia remisionConductor, que tendrá al menos, idRemisión + idConductor. Y lo gestionas mediante dos tablas intermedias separadas. Así puede resultarte más fácil.

Comment: gracias, me has dado una buena idea. ando algo perdido aun xD